# Subject-Verb Agreement – Has or Have?

Tags: grammar

Has or have below? I say 'have'. Compound subject requires a plural verb, right?

*"I love the people, the culture, and (most importantly) the food that New York and Greenwich Village, in particular, have to offer."*

Comment: Shouldn't it be "New York, and Greenwich Village in particular, ..."? Without the comma after "New York", it suggests that New York and Greenwich Village are two different places.

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

> I love everything that opera, in particular La Traviata, has to offer.

and

> I love everything that operas, in particular La Traviata, have to offer.

Since you're referring to New York, and Greenwich Village as a subset of it, logically, the singular applies.

Had you said something like 'capital cities and their specialist districts, like New York and Greenwich Village', the plural would apply.